# Give a formal proof that, $\frac{n^4 + 8n}{n^2+9} \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

For convergence at infinity, do I need to show that a  $|a_{n} - \infty| > \epsilon$? All guidance is appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: We don't use the term 'converge' when the expression gets infinitely large. Also, we need to show that we can take a positive integer $n$ so that $a_n>N$ for any $N>0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How formal do you want this?

Going back to the definition, you have that $u_n \to +\infty$ if for every $M \in \mathbb{R}$, you can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $u_n \ge M$ whenever $n \ge N$. In your case:

$$u_n=\frac{n^4+8n}{n^2+9} \ge \frac{n^4}{n^2+9}\ge \frac{n^4}{n^3}=n$$
where $n^3 > n^2+9$ holds for $n\ge3$.

This means that for an arbitrary $M$, you can take $N=M$ and you'll have $u_n \ge M$ for all $n \ge N$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $$\frac{n^4+8n}{n^2+9} \geq \frac{n^4}{n^2+9} = \frac{n^2}{1+\frac{9}{n^2}} >= \frac{n^2}{2}$$ where the second inequality holds for all $n \geq 3$.

Comment: Didn't you mean to write something like $9n^{\color{red}{-2}}$?

Comment: Your second inequality is weird...and thus your equality is wrong: it should be $\;\cfrac{n^2}{2n^2}=\cfrac12\;$ . I think you meant something different.

Answer (score 1):

we have the following 
$$\frac{n^4\left(1+\frac{8}{n^3}\right)}{n^2\left(1+\frac{9}{n^2}\right)}$$=$$\frac{n^2\left(1+8/n^3\right)}{1+9/n^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn to Polynomial long division:
$$\begin{align} \frac{n^4 + 8n}{n^2 + 9} &= n^2 + 9 \overline{\smash{\left)\vphantom{n^{4^4}}\right.}n^4 + 8n} \\
&= n^2 - 9 + \frac{8n+81}{n^2+9}. \end{align}$$

The remainder term clearly $\rightarrow 0$, the constant term does nothing, so the expression overall diverged.